# Unet not sync a float value between client-server , server-client

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I try to sync float value between server-client.

On server screen have boss HpBar script with MAXHP value setup in scene.

player prefab have their own boss HP UI and localhp script that will get currently boss HP value from a HpBar script in the server.

when the user press Attack button it will send damage value to HpBar script then it should update to player prefab. but it doesn't sync together. thanks

picture here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji8LZ.jpg

localPlayerHPBAR Script:

```cs
public class localHpBar : NetworkBehaviour
{

    public HpBar serverHp;
    public float localhpPoint;
    public Image localhpBar;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        serverHp = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<HpBar>();
        //Get OBJ of serverHP
    }

    public void sendDamage(float dmg)
    {
        serverHp.TakeDamage(dmg); //SendDamageToserver
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    { 
        //get HP point from server
        localhpPoint = serverHp.sum;
        localhpBar.fillAmount = localhpPoint;
    }
}
```

SERVER HpBar

```cs
public class HpBar : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public Image HP;
    public float MaxHP;
    float currentHP;
    public float localhp;
    [SyncVar] public float sum;

    void Start()
    { 
        //set CURRENT HP
        currentHP = MaxHP;
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void rpcDamage(float dmg)
    {       
        sum = currentHP / MaxHP;
        HP.fillAmount = sum;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(float dmg)
    {

        //recieve DamageFrom client
        currentHP = currentHP - dmg;
        rpcDamage(currentHP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that a [`[SyncVar]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetStateSync.html) is only synchronized Server → Client(s).

**Never** in the other direction. Changing this value on the client won't affect the server or other clients.

You are changing `sum` using a `[ClientRpc]`. A `[ClientRpc]` is invoked by the **server** but executed on all clients. You are not even allowed to call this as a client.

---

What you rather should do is making the `TakeDamage` method a `[Command]` so it is invoked by the client but only executed on the **server** where you then are allowed to change the synced value like

```c#
// This is called by clients but executed on the server
[Command]
public void CmdTakeDamage(float dmg)
{
    currentHP -= dmg;

    sum = currentHP / MaxHP;

    // actually pass on the new sum
    rpcDamage(sum);
}

// This is called ONLY by the server but executed on all clients
[ClientRpc]
// also make sure the prefix is capital Rpc otherwise it might not work
void RpcDamage(float newSum)
{
    // if you set sum here then you should simply remove the 
    // [SyncVar] since you already sync it "manually"
    // I would actually do this since it is not guaranteed that the syncvar
    // transfers its new value before this method is executed
    // on the other hand syncvar is additionally synchronized when connecting a new client
    // so you might have to do it "manually"
    sum = newSum;
    HP.fillAmount = sum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. the code work and value sync when i press attack btn on host. but in client it not update a value.thanks